# How can I code desktop monitoring software?

Tags: c#, monitoring, desktop, spying

I have to develop a tool for monitoring helpdesk agents. I can figure out how to capture keyboard events and mouse events; however I need to capture the control that emitted/consumed the event too. Is it possible to find that out?

Comment: You may be legit, but unfortunately the answer to this question would also be a good answer to "How do I write an effective keylogger to steal people's bank login credentials?"

Comment: Every technique has a bright and a dark side. You can harm other people with nearly every solution you find here - that's not the question. And no reason to downvote it.

Comment: this idea is a good one ;) i believe he is a software engineer of a call center company ;) and the boss wants to make sure all the employees are not doing facebook and being productive instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need windows hooks to pick up the events. These are really the province of native code. Try asking again with Win32 tag replacing the C# tag.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code from [Stephen Toub's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) to add a shortcut to my application in the system tray. The comments were quite useful as well.